# How to append menu to some element, rather then <body>? appendTo?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-contextmenu

If i use Jquery Context menu on my page, then all html code appears inside BODY tag. Right before closing 
I need that this **html code** located inside MY div with id="mydiv" .

I need it for my z-index issue (in fullscreen mode this menu not visible, because it not inside #mydiv element)

Some plugins has **appendTo** option, but Jquery Context menu is not i suppose.
How to solve it?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it within the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you add a fiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

Currently (v1.18.1) there is no such option. You might open a feature request for this.

Comment: Never mind. I already figured it out. In your source code i've changed "body" to "#mydiv". And it works as i planned. Great plugin!